# dllexport function from another dll

Tags: visual-c++, dll, dllexport

If I use a program called "DLL Export Viewer" to look at functions exported from the api-ms-win* files in system32 they have exported functions not with an address within the dll itself but to another dll where the address is something like "kernel32.OpenProcess", how would would I recreate this in a C++ dll?

Comment: I think you are talking about [Windows API sets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/apiindex/windows-apisets).

Comment: I think what I'm trying to ask is how to create stub or proxy functions in my dll.

Comment: This is done with a "forwarder entry" in the export table.  You need a .def file, specify the forwarder with thisname = otherdll.othername.  I don't see great google hits, but it is mentioned [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20121116-00/?p=6073).